# crosstab query : count a number occurence in a row

Tags: pivot

I have a crosstab query that shows 1 and 0 in the value area.

```
          Function 1 Function 2 ..Function n 
project 1    1          0             1
project 2    0          0             1
..
project n    1          0             0
```

I need to add a column before Function 1 e.g ( Confirmed) which will count the values of 1's in every row.
I tried the case and if

```
SELECT 
  ((CASE WHEN Function1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  + (CASE WHEN Function2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  + (CASE WHEN Function3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS sum_of_nulls
FROM (query name)
```

but did not work.
Can you please help on that ?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: "*did not work*" is not a valid error message in any DBMS. You need to explain what exactly "did not work". Did you get an error? If yes what was the exact error message? Are you getting wrong values? If yes what are the values you get and what did you expect